# Why can't I move a file into an NTFS directory mounted RW?

Tags: move

There are two OSes on my PC : Debian8.1 and Win7.
The Win7 was mounted on /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7 when Debian8.1 was loaded.
[image]

I then tried to move a Debian iso without success.

Why can't I move the iso file into `/media/root/1610D6B410D699D7`?

```
mv  /home/debian8.1.iso  /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7
mv: cannot create regular file ‘/media/root/1610D6B410D699D7/debian8.1.iso’: Permission denied
```

[image]

It is RW .
[image]

```
root@debian:~# cat  /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=250719,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=404492k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sda7 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=23,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda9 /windows vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
rpc_pipefs /run/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/109 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=202248k,mode=700,uid=109,gid=117 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/0 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=202248k,mode=700 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/0/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0 0 0
/dev/sda5 /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7 ntfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1 0 0
/dev/sda8 /media/root/fb2c100d-434c-4c37-a164-f0d000bc522a ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: I guess your windows partition is mounted *read only*. Run `findmnt` to check it out.

Comment: try `more /proc/mounts` and check if your drive is mounted read-only (ro instead of rw)

Comment: Your `mv` command is missing a parameter.

Comment: i add the lost parameter,and test the command ,problem remain.

Comment: What happens when you try 'chmod +w /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7' ?
What does ls -ls /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7 show?

Comment: grep for the mount point in `/proc/mounts`. If there is a `dmask` value, can you tell us what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be an NTFS problem. 
Look [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133029). 
Try:

```
sudo aptitude update && aptitude install ntfs-3g

umount /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7

mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7

chmod +w /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7
chmod u+w /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7
```

then move it.

Comment: root@debian:~# umount /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7

Comment: root@debian:~# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7

Comment: ntfs-3g-mount: failed to access mountpoint /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7: No such file or directory

Comment: mkdir /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /media/root/1610D6B410D699D7